# Perl hash and array + sort

Tags: perl

The code speaks for itself, didn't use sort in code because I unknown your use this is content code in perl.

```
/bash/perl
%ttys = ();
my @lsarray = `cat /home/delkav/labs-scripts/grep`;
my @array;
$array[0] = <STDIN>; < ONE
$array[1] = <STDIN>; < TWO
$array[2] = <STDIN>; < TRHEE
$array[3] = <STDIN>; < FOUR
$array[4] = <STDIN>; < FIVE
$array[5] = <STDIN>; < SIX
$array[6] = <STDIN>; < SEVEN
$array[7] = <STDIN>; < EIGHT
$array[8] = <STDIN>; < NINE
@ttys{@lsarray} = @array;
print "@{[%ttys]}\n"
```

content in /home/delkav/labs-scripts/grep is :

```
$90850
$0
$389
$469
$670
$750
$684
$21744
$604
```

the printing out the script

```
$684
SEVEN
$469
FOUR
$21744
EIGHT
$670
FIVE
$389
TRHEE
$90850
ONE
$0
TWO
$750
SIX
$604
NINE
```

I need the output how this.

```
$90850
ONE
$0
TWO
$389
THREE
$469
FOUR
$670
FIVE
$750
SIX
$684
SEVEN
$21744
EIGHT
$604
NINE
```

well, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you need to preserve the order, you shouldn't use a hash, because hash functions don't maintain the order. instead you should use an array ref. Maybe like this:

```
#!/bash/perl
my @ttys;
my @lsarray = map { chomp; $_ } `cat /home/delkav/labs-scripts/grep`;
my @array;
chomp($array[$_] = <>) for 0..8;
push @ttys, [$array[$_], $lsarray[$_]] for 0..$#array;
print "$_->[0]\n$_->[1]\n" foreach @ttys;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe as this:

```
print "$_\n$ttys{$_}\n" for @lsarray;
```

Comment: note that in the OPs code, the elements of @lsarray and the keys and values of %tty all have newlines already

Answer (score 0):

You should *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every program. You should also open the data file and read it in Perl rather than shelling out to `cat`.

This program does what you need.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', '/home/delkav/labs-scripts/grep' or die $!;

my @numbers = qw/ ONE TWO THREE FOUR FIVE SIX SEVEN EIGHT NINE TEN /;

my $i = 0;
while (<$fh>) {
  print;
  print $numbers[$i++], "\n";
}
```